# What items are excluded from Re-Tail premium list?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

What items **can't** be on the Re-Tail premium chalk board list? I want fossils but I've never seen it on the list nor can I find an answer anywhere. Is there a full list hidden somewhere of everything on the list? If not I could help build one for future use. I need one badly myself as I'm running out of room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fossils do show up on the chalk board for paying extra. I can verify that from personal experience. I don't believe I've ever seen a specific fossil, just the generic "Fossils".

As for what is excluded from being bought at premium? I'm not aware of anything specific. I've seen pretty much anything you can imagine show up on that board in one form or another on the two copies of the game I have. It can be anything from "Shoes" or "Furniture" to something specific like "Crucian carp".

Your question is a bit confusing though as when something is on the chalk board it's because Reese is paying extra for that item. You get fossils by digging up the X marks around town and having them appraised at the museum and you then donate them. It took me almost a year of grinding fossils to get a 100% set. Extra fossil sets can be taken to Cyrus to be turned into miniatures and beyond that you can sell them for Bells all the time and get paid well for them. They have to be appraised before you do anything with them though or Reese will pay almost nothing for them. If you're hording extras, just sell them and free up the space.

Comment: I was asking if the fossils could go on premium. Thanks so much. Lol I wasn't asking for fossils at the shop, I've been saving em in my storage for when they do go premium.